# Cropping a Base64 PNG in-memory using PURE JavaScript on the client side w/o using canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Context: JavaScript, as part of a SDK (can be on node.js or browser).

Start point: I have a base64 string that's actually a base64 encoded PNG image (I got it from selenium webdriver - takeScreenshot).

Question: How do I crop it?

The techniques involving the canvas seem irrelevant (or am I wrong?). My code runs as part of tests - probably on node.js. The canvas approach doesn't seem to fit here and might also cause additional noise in the image.

All the libraries I found either deal with streams (maybe I should convert the string to stream somehow?) or deal directly with the UI by adding a control (irrelevant for me).

Isn't there something like (promises and callbacks omitted for brevity):

```
 var base64png = driver.takeScreenshot();
 var png = new PNG(base64png);
 return png.crop(50, 100, 20, 80).toBase64();
```

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my previous comment as an answer:

Anyone looking to do this will need to decode the image to get the raw image data using a library such as [node-pngjs](http://github.com/niegowski/node-pngjs) and manipulate the data yourself (perhaps there is a library for such operations that doesn't rely on the canvas).

Answer (score 4):

Considering you wish to start with base64 string and end with cropped base64 string (image), here is the following code:

```
var Stream = require('stream');
var gm = require('gm');

var base64png = driver.takeScreenshot();
var stream = new Stream();

stream.on('data', function(data) {
  print data
});

gm(stream, 'my_image.png').crop(WIDTH, HEIGHT, X, Y).stream(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  var data = '';

  stdout.on('readable', function() {
    data += stream.read().toString('base64');
  });
  stream.on('end', function() {
    // DO something with your new base64 cropped img
  });
});

stream.emit('data', base64png);
```

Be aware that it is unfinished, and might need some polishing or debugging (I am in no means a node.js guru), but the idea is next:

1. Convert string into stream
2. Read stream into [GM module](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/)
3. Manipulate the image
4. Save it into a stream
5. Convert stream back into 64base string

Comment: Thank you but installing GraphicsMagick is not an option for me in my use case. That's basically the part I'm looking for - how to do the image manipulation purely by javascript computation - not by using external software or files.

Comment: @alandarev I don't think there's a straightforward way to do this short of just using canvas (`node-canvas` server-side) if you don't want to use GM. You'll still need libcairo as a dependency though

Comment: Thanks @ChrisT - I'm aware of this option but, as you yourself mentioned, requires drawing on canvas and an additional dependency. I'm considering to write something myself and share it.

Comment: @alandarev caman uses the canvas and would require `node-canvas` to use server side. I'm not sure it's worth going through the effort to reinvent the wheel to bring a CPU heavy operation like image processing into JS land, but if you are 100% adding dependencies that's what you've got to do. Good luck!

Comment: @DoronZavelevsky This library might be of some use to you as far as getting the raw image data from your string for processing: https://github.com/niegowski/node-pngjs

Comment: Thank you @ChrisT - that was actually the library I've decided to go with. As an  interim solution I used it for encoding/decoding png - and did the cropping myself by modifying the rgba array. Later on I want to see how I can avoid going through the file system. If you'd like you can combine your comment with this one as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @DoronZavelevsky just out of curiosity what do you mean going through the file system? It looks like that library accepts any stream so you can create a readable stream from in-memory instead of writing to the filesystem (using your own mock-stream or [stream-buffers](https://www.npmjs.org/package/stream-buffers))

Comment: @ChrisT - you're correct - I wasn't clear: What I meant is that in my hurry I just went ahead and created the streams using actual files (I used temp). I did some reading and saw that there are options to create these streams in-memory but didn't find anything I felt reassured by - so I used the file system. Hope I clarified the issue.
quoting from the link you provided: "Not supposed to be a speed demon, it's more for tests/debugging or weird edge cases". I'll keep looking.

Comment: @DoronZavelevsky Gotcha, sounds like you can just use a `TransformStream` that does nothing. This way you're just using the built-in node streams library with no additional cruft (except for an extra but trivial function call) For example: https://gist.github.com/ilsken/e8deb3980051fa5c8fb1

Comment: I tried this inside the Meteor framework on server side, but it tells me that the stream is not readable..